# Не считываются float переменные из файла

Tags: c, файлы

Задача состоит в том, чтобы считать из txt файла 3 целые переменные на первой строке и 2 вещественные на второй строке, а затем найти наибольшее среди целых и наименьшее среди вещественных. С целыми переменными не возникает трудностей, а вещественные не получается считать.

[image: data.txt - те самые переменные]

[image]

```
int int1, int2, int3, max_int1, max_int2;
float float1, float2, min_float;

FILE *data;
data = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if(data == NULL)
        printf("Read error");
    else
        fscanf(data, "%d %d %d %f %f", &int1, &int2, &int3, &float1, &float2);
fclose(data);

max_int1 = (int1 > int2) ? int1 : int2;
max_int2 = (max_int1 > int3) ? max_int1 : int3;
min_float = (float1 < float2) ? float1 : float2;

printf("Максимальное целое число = %d\n", max_int2);
printf("Минимальное дробное число = %.2f", min_float); 

return 0;
```

Comment: Если у вас русская локаль, то разделителем целой и дробной части должна быть не точка, а запятая

Comment: можно выборочно установить для числовой точки Си-шную локаль : `setlocale ( LC_NUMERIC , "C" ) ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за комментарии, замена точки на запятую действительно помогло.